# How to query an AJAX imported table (instead of a local table) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-sheets-api

Currently, I have a script that searches column 1 of a locally-stored table, and returns the result from column 2 from the same row. Based on that result, it logs something to the console.

Here it is action. It searches the table for "dragon" in column 1, returns "2" from Column 2, then the script logs "The result is two." to the console.

```js
var username = 'dragon'
const searchDataSetByKey = (dataSet, key) => {
  return dataSet.find((data) => data[0] === key)
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  var tableToArray = Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'))
  .reduce((_tableToArray, tableRow, tableRowIndex) => {
    if(tableRowIndex !== 0) {
      var tableData = tableRow.querySelectorAll('td')
      var key = tableData.item(0).innerText
      var value = tableData.item(1).innerText
      _tableToArray.push([key, value])
    }
    return _tableToArray
  }, [])
  var searchString = searchDataSetByKey(tableToArray,username).toString()
var oneSearch = searchString.indexOf("1")
var twoSearch = searchString.indexOf("2")
var threeSearch = searchString.indexOf("3")
if (oneSearch >= 0) {
console.log('The result is one!');}
else if (twoSearch >= 0) {
  console.log('This result is two.');}
  else if (threeSearch >= 0) {
  console.log('The answer is three! :)');}
})
```

```html
<html>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>1/2/3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>wisp</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>husky</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>dragon</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>woop</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>e6</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is great for locally-stored tables. The issue is, I'd like to get the same result from a Google Sheet. I've found a way to store the info from a Google Sheet into a HTML table using AJAX. The code for this can be seen here:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var spData = null;
  function doData(json) {
      spData = json.feed.entry;
  }
  
  function drawCell(tr, val) {
      var td = $("<td/>");
      tr.append(td);
      td.append(val);
      return td;
  }
  function drawRow(table, rowData) {
   if (rowData == null) return null;
   if (rowData.length == 0) return null;
   var tr = $("<tr/>");
   table.append(tr);
   for(var c=0; c<rowData.length; c++) {
    drawCell(tr, rowData[c]);
   }
   return tr;
  }
  
  function drawTable(parent) {
   var table = $("<table/>");
   parent.append(table);
   return table;
  }
  
  function readData(parent) {
      var data = spData;
      var table = drawTable(parent);
      var rowData = [];
      
      for(var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
          var cell = data[r]["gs$cell"];
          var val = cell["$t"];
          if (cell.col == 1) {
              drawRow(table, rowData);
              rowData = [];
          }
          rowData.push(val);
      }
      drawRow(table, rowData);
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
      readData($("#data"));
  });

  </script>
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1P9DhWOHcl14Y7-P5wCxTm-sUceckGquPoOobO75XhvM/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  form {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="data"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I was wondering if there was any way of achieving what was done in the local HTML table, with this AJAX imported HTML table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly the same work that you need to do, albeit at a different time - i.e in response to a different event. Do it straight after you've loaded the table, instead of straight after you've received the DOMContentLoaded event from the document. Here's an alternate way to go looking.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var spData = null;
  function doData(json) {
      spData = json.feed.entry;
  }
  
  function drawCell(tr, val) {
      var td = $("<td/>");
      tr.append(td);
      td.append(val);
      return td;
  }
  function drawRow(table, rowData) {
   if (rowData == null) return null;
   if (rowData.length == 0) return null;
   var tr = $("<tr/>");
   table.append(tr);
   for(var c=0; c<rowData.length; c++) {
    drawCell(tr, rowData[c]);
   }
   return tr;
  }
  
  function drawTable(parent) {
   var table = $("<table/>");
   parent.append(table);
   return table;
  }
  
  function readData(parent) {
      var data = spData;
      var table = drawTable(parent);
      var rowData = [];
      
      for(var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
          var cell = data[r]["gs$cell"];
          var val = cell["$t"];
          if (cell.col == 1) {
              drawRow(table, rowData);
              rowData = [];
          }
          rowData.push(val);
      }
      drawRow(table, rowData);
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
      readData($("#data"));
      searchTable( 'dragon', document.querySelector('table') );
  });

  function searchTable(searchStr, target)
  {
        let rows = Array.from( target.querySelectorAll('tr') );
        rows.forEach( (row,idx,col) => {
                                let firstCell = row.querySelector('td').textContent;
                                if (firstCell == searchStr)
                                {
                                      let cell2 = row.querySelectorAll('td')[1].textContent;
                                      console.log(`${searchStr} found in row ${idx}`);
                                      console.log(`col 2 of row #${idx} is: ${cell2}`);
                                }
                          }
                    );
  }


  </script>
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1P9DhWOHcl14Y7-P5wCxTm-sUceckGquPoOobO75XhvM/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  form {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="data"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much. I love the method to search the data. Much cleaner and efficient. Thanks again!